# Get number from the string (RegExp)

Tags: java, regex

Could you please help me to write java regexp for getting number from the next strings:

1. animal 1 animal
2. 1 animal
3. animal 1

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: to match the numbers `\\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of answers to this question in stackoverflow. Next time search before you ask!

Here is a simple code which gives what you want:

```
String str= "animal 1 animal";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");

    Matcher match = p.matcher(str);

    while (match.find()) {
        System.out.println(match.group());
    }
```

It is the same with your other Strings.. just change the value of "str" or create another variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`, someting like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(myString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // Use Integer.parseInt(m.group()); to get an int
}
```

Comment: This also finds negative numbers.

Comment: `5.45` also called as a number .

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The OP didn't specify what kind of numbers. If you want to parse floating point as well then you need to account for the locale as well: in some countries the decimal separator is different, for example `5,45`.

Comment: >>The OP didn't specify what kind of numbers.
You can find integer numbers in the sample.

Comment: @DarkDust op didn't specify negative numbers also.